# Suppress latex output in scripts

Tags: linux

I run a sequence of latex commands from a bash script. Since the latex output polutes the scripts own output I would like to suppress it. But sending the output to /dev/null will make the latex process inaccesible for the user. Hence it could be killed only manually in case there is a compilation error. How can I control latex from within the script. I.e. suppress the output and exit the process in case of error.

Comment: Did you try `pdflatex --interaction=batchmode`?

Comment: Try this: `pdflatex -halt-on-error file.tex 1> /dev/null
[[ $? -eq 1 ]] && echo "msg in case of erros" && exit`

With this, in case of errors, the msg will appear. Otherwise, the output will be send to null.

Comment: @Thiago this appears to work, but hangs if the `file.tex` doesn't exist (which is one possible error).

Comment: So you can try to check first if the file exists. The variable `$?` has the result of any command. Usually it could be zero or not. You can test it.

Comment: I am using now `latex --interaction=nonstopmode "file.tex" &>/dev/null`. Then I check the exit state in $?. The halt-on-error is not appropriate for me as I don't want it to stop for errors in individual files (if there are nasty errors in many files it can take me ages to confirm all of them). Whats the difference to `--interaction=batchmode`?

Comment: @Sigur Can you turn your comments into an answer, please?

Comment: Did you try to use `yes`? E.g., `yes '^D' | pdflatex "$file"` (where ^D is input with Ctrl+V+Ctrl+D). With this, if pdflatex is waiting for some input, it receives a nice EOF, so user doesn't need to kill it. `-halt-on-error` fails if file doesn't exists or if it never finishes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As asked above by *egreg*, I'm turning my comments into answer.

I'm using this command om my script and I'm satisfied with it.

```
pdflatex -halt-on-error file.tex 1> /dev/null 
[[ $? -eq 1 ]] && echo "msg in case of erros" && exit
```

In case of errors, the *msg* will appear. Otherwise, the output will be send to null.

Now, you can try to improve with a command to search for your file before running `pdflatex`.

Comment: Not the best `bash` I've seen in my life... `1>` is funny, so is the `&& exit`. Also, `[[ $? -eq 1 ]]` is not the best idea, just in case `pdflatex` returns another (non-zero) code. How about `(( $? )) && echo "msg in case of errors"` instead ?

Comment: I don't know. For me, it works! But if there are better solutions, thanks for helping.